# Using ggplot2 in R to plot a Kaplan-Meier curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a KM curve using ggplot2. My code generates a plot with the survival package but it doesn't look very nice and I want to try using ggplot2. 
This first like generates a plot in the survival package

```
km.as.gendercategory <- survfit(Survobject ~ donorrecipientgender, data = Cleaned27.7.17)
```

But when I use the ggkm in ggplot2

```
ggkm(km.as.gendercategory,timeby=365)
```

I get this error msg

> Error in theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0.7),
>   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  : formal argument
>   "panel.grid.minor" matched by multiple actual arguments

What does this mean?

Comment: Where does this function `ggkm()` comes from? Please add the packages additionally loaded and add some sample data to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

That means that whatever 'theme' you are using, you have 2 arguments for the `panel.grid.minor`. For example, when I make a custom theme for my graphs, if I put 2 lines of (whatever argument maybe) let's say I use

```
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,color="black",vjust=3),
          axis.title.x=element_text(size=18,color="black",vjust=-1),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=-1.2)
          axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=-1.2)
          )
```

That is gonna give you an error because, as you notice, there are 2 statements for `axis.title.x`. and each one of them says different things.
The error I would get using this code is:

```
Error in theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "black",  :formal argument "axis.title.x" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Which goes for other arguments as well. However, unless you post your actual code with sample data, any solution would be a guess. What I would do is look for duplicate statements for panel.grid.minor.